# Stormy water like Temple Run 2 for Mobile

Tags: unity, water

How can I make stormy water like they did in Temple Run 2. I've tried with Unity Water Pro to achieve the same result but when I include it in the project the frame rate crashes to 3 frames per second.

Unity Water basic doesn't fulfill the requirements at all. So is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We end up with having a static mesh and animating it. Add some particle effects and we can make it stormy and mobile ready. I didn't require any real water reflection so this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's an asset for that. The asset also has a web player demo. Check out the unity store :)

Here's your link.
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7768

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14109

Comment: You should link him to the asset as well. This answer can be improved.

Comment: Yeah sure. I just did :)

Comment: Hi Farhaan. Thanks for answering, but that's not the effect I am looking towards. They are basically waterfall particles. I can't make stormy water for a river with it. I need to make a game on Kayaking which needs that kind of water.

Comment: if youre looking to invest more in your game this asset might go along way. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/4481  

just give the wind parameters and you can create a storm but its way to costly

Comment: Well that's not for mobile :-(